CA Certificate for HP printer
While setting up newly purchased printer HP Laserjet Pro M479dw, I got an issue with the scan to mail option. Unlike the older model, this one requires a CA certificate to operate the scan to mail feature.
How do I generate the necessary certificate?
The printer is connected to simple home network and can be set up via web interface.

Normally this is not something you generate for the printer – it wants you to upload an existing CA root that your mail server currently uses, so that the printer could verify the server's own TLS/SSL certificate against it (in the same way as web browsers validate them).
Look at your mail server's TLS certificate to see which CA root it was issued by, then export it from Windows certmgr.msc or copy from Linux /etc/ssl/certs or download from the CA's website.
